# rcharts nvd3 % format - precision to one tenth percent

Tags: nvd3.js, rcharts

I'm using lineChart from Rcharts nvd3, and I'd like to format the y values as a percent precise to one tenth of a %. I can format as a percent as below, but when I hover over the points, it only shows a % precise to 1%, I can't get it to be precise to the tenth decimal place.

```
p$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!
        function(d) {return d3.format('%')(d)}
        !#"
)
```

I tried doing this, but didn't work:

```
p$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!
            function(d) {return d3.format('.0%')(d)}
            !#"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
p$yAxis(tickFormat = "#!
        function(d) {return d3.format('.1%')(d)}
        !#"
)
```

From the [d3 wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#numbers):

> The precision indicates how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a value formatted with types "f" and "%"